# Django1.9: No model matches the given query

Tags: python, django, view, model

I am following a tutorial to create a blog.
The code is correct according to the tutorial.
The only difference is that I use Django 1.9 instead of 1.8

Calling the `Post` model in the view without

```
publish__year=year,
publish__month=month,
publish__day=day)
```

doesn't return a 404 Error - `No Post matches the given query.`

This is `view.py`

```
def post_detail(request, year, month, day, post):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=post,
                                   status='published',)
                                   #publish__year=year,
                                   #publish__month=month,
                                   #publish__day=day)
    return render(request, 'blog/post/detail.html', {'post': post})
```

The model part looks like that `models.py`

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    ...
```

Any ideas why the query is not found?

EDIT:

The URL looks like `localhost/blog/2016/07/30/second-post-entry/`

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post_detail', args=[self.publish.year,
                                                 self.publish.strftime('%m'),
                                                 self.publish.strftime('%d'),
                                                 self.slug])
```

It seems that those are the problem:

```
self.publish.strftime('%m'), # eg. == 07, but publish__month == 7
self.publish.strftime('%d')  # eg. == 30, publish__day == 30
```

Comment: If you get `No Post matches the given query`, that means that there is no post that matched that year, month and day. We don't know what posts you have in your database, what their publish date is, or what url you tried to visit, so we can't tell you what the problem is beyond that.

Comment: @Alasdair The structure of the URL is what i find in my database: `print(posts[1].publish)
2016-07-30 17:47:28+00:00`

Comment: Okay. 7 != '07' self.publish.strftime('%m') != publish__month ... so how to call the month with 0? What would be the right way now?

Comment: Try converting to an integer, e.g. `publish__month=int(month)`

Answer (score 0):

As I got it, you can either change `self.publish.strftime('%m')` and                                                 `self.publish.strftime('%d')` to `self.publish.month` and `self.publish.day`,
either you can convert passed data into int `publish__year=int(year), publish__month=int(month), publish__day=int(day)`. That should do the trick.

Comment: @Alasdair @Artem-Kolontay Converting `month = '07'` to `int(month)` didn't help ... so I was wondering.

I figured out that the issue was to `import pytz` in my `setting.py`.
This way it solved the problem. But didn't understand a 100% why. So it has something to do with my database time types? Could someone explain or refer?